# Are there any well know REGEX libraries for .NET specifically for byte[] arrays?

Tags: c#, regex, arrays

I understand that .NET's regex works with strings, but I need an implementation for byte[] arrays. Are there any open source implementation in .NET? Does byte[] regex exists for any other programming language other than C# which I can use to build a wrapper for it in C#?

My limitation is that I have to stay within byte arrays. So cannot do any conversions to strings.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Why don't you convert the text in the byte array to a string? Or is your input binary data?

Comment: Actually I don't have the option to convert, I only have to work on byte arrays.

Comment: Why is Darin Dimitrov answer no option?

Comment: If I want to match some part of a byte array by looking the byte entries, then writing up lengthy code just to find some pattern. That is why I posted the question to know if Regex for byte arrays existed. I know Regex in .NET works on strings only, I am right now limited to byte arrays. So I have a stay with in byte arrays.

Comment: Well you could convert the byte array into a string in a format that actually represents the byte array (like a string of '0's and '1's, base64 or hex) and then use regexp on that.

Answer (score 6):

Regular expressions work with strings. A byte array can contain just about any data. So if you want to use regular expressions convert this byte array into a string using the encoding that was used to encode it. For example if your byte array represents a UTF-8 encoded string:

```
byte[] buffer = ...
string foo = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
// Go ahead and use regexes on foo
```

Comment: Actually I don't have the option to convert, I only have to work on byte arrays

Comment: @Wajih, then you cannot use regular expressions. This simply doesn't make sense. Care to elaborate what prevents you from converting the byte array into string?

Comment: Well it makes sense while matching portions of byte arrays so I thought there might be regular expression that can handle byte arrays as well.